# How to set right alignment of column in the grid of silver light

Tags: silverlight, grid

How can i set horizontal alignment of column in the grid of silver light???
Please help

below in my xaml code

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" x:Name="grdSalesOrder" TabIndex="22" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PCVSaleOrders}" SelectionMode="Single" Height="{Binding Path=GridHeight}" Width="953">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=CustomerName}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" Header="Customer Name" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Status}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" Header="Status" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PriceAmt}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" Header="Price Amount" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the property CellStyle

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" x:Name="grdSalesOrder" TabIndex="22" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PCVSaleOrders}" SelectionMode="Single" Height="{Binding Path=GridHeight}" Width="953">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
 <sdk:DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="MyStyle" Binding="{Binding Path=CustomerName}" CanUserReorder="True"     CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" Header="Customer Name" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="MyStyle" Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"   CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" Header="Status" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="MyStyle" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceAmt}"   CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" Header="Price Amount" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

And you style can be set like this :

```
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="sdk:DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCellTemplate}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
```

Now you can chose what you want to change..
Hope it helps!